# How to compress a video recorded using QuickTime without reducing the quality

Tags: audio, video, quicktime

I've been using QuickTime to record my online classes, unfortunately the video sizes are very large (about 2.5GB for a 2hr long video). I tried recording the same classes using Zoom and the the file was around 500mb (almost 4 times lesser), and the quality was almost the same. I have tried:

1. Using VLC to compress it, but for some reason the 2hr long file is reduced to just 5 seconds (the quality remains the same though).
2. Exporting it to a lower resolution using Quick time, but the quality became very poor and the audio was muffled.

I record all my new videos using Zoom now, but I need my old files also and they're simply taking up too much of space.

Comment: "Without reducing quality"—you will not get any significant reduction in file size if you don't compromise in quality. Handbrake allows you to fine-tune the encode so that you can get some nice settings which gives acceptable quality and significantly lower filesizes. I've found QuickTIme's automatic settings are quite bad!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Transcode with HandBrake

Use [HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr) to re-encode your original videos.

Try the default preset/profile **Fast 1080p30**. This will likely be enough to meet your needs.

[image: HandBrake on macOS]

HandBrake is free and open source. The tool uses `ffmpeg` underneath to provide access to a wide range of possible encodings.

Comment: As another comment points out, this is not lossless — it will be losing _some_ quality.  However, it's still almost certainly the best option; you should be able to get something that looks extremely close, at a fraction of the file size.  (Especially if you tune some of the advanced settings that give better quality at the cost of longer encode times.  Using a fine/ultrafine denoising filter can help too.)